# Coordinator layout too large when number of items in recycler view is small

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have problem with RecyclerView in Coordinator layout.
If the number of items in recycler view is small, the size of Coordinator is larger than screen. When scrolled to the end, the space for recycler view + additional space is the size of screen height. Is this normal behaviour? Or is there to fix it? If I set the recycler height to "match_parent" then the whole recyclerview is the size of the screen...

Edit: I want the views not to scroll when there is not enough items. And also if there is 1-2 items below the screen, the Recycler should not be as high as the whole screen and only just scroll the few items.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="#dddddd">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:background="#777777">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/cardMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:text="Red Dwarf characters"/>
            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#aaaaaa"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" 
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Recycler view height set to match_parent
[image]

Comment: what is it that you are trying to achieve? you want the recycler view to only take the place below the appbar layout?

Comment: +1 to @hopeman 's comment. Also i would suggest that you look at: http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

Comment: I am trying to achieve, that if there is not enough items, the view will not scroll.